# Django empty self.args in ListView when <pk> in urls.py

Tags: python, django, listview, django-views, django-class-based-views

I want to get a Project name for Sample. It should be in self.args because my urls.py looks like that (there is a lot of urls so I will post only important ones):

projects/urls.py

```
app_name = 'projects'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^$", ProjectListView.as_view(), name="projects_list"),
    url(r"^(\w+)/robjects/", include("robjects.urls")),
    url(r"^(\w+)/tags/$", TagsListView.as_view(), name="tag_list"),
...
]
```

robjects/urls.py

```
app_name="robjects"
urlpatterns = [
...
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/samples/', include("samples.urls")),
]
```

samples/urls.py

```
app_name="samples"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^list/$', SampleListView.as_view(), name='sample_list_view'),
    url(r'^create/$', SampleCreateView.as_view(), name='sample_create_view'),
    url(r'^(?P<sample_id>[0-9]+)/update/$', SampleUpdateView.as_view(), name='sample_update'),
    url(r'^(?P<sample_id>[0-9]+)/delete/$', SampleDeleteView.as_view(), name='sample_delete'),
]
```

I want to get project_name, that is the '(\w+)' part of projects/urls.py. To do that I wrote that code in samples/views.py. I tried to do project_name = self.args[0] but my args are empty.

class SampleListView(ListView):
        model = Sample
        template_name = "samples/samples_list.html"

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """A base view for displaying a list of objects."""
        # check if project exists
        try:
            pk = kwargs['pk']
            robject = Robject.objects.get(id=pk)
            # add project to view attributes
            self.robject = robject
        except Robject.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        print(self.args) # it should be a project name here
        return super(SampleListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Overwrite orginal qs and add filtering by robject
        """

        # original queryset
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        print('args, ',self.args)
        print('kwargs', self.kwargs)
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        robject = Robject.objects.get(id=pk)
        return qs.filter(robject=self.robject)
```

This is the output :

```
args,  ()
kwargs {'pk': '27'}
```

I want to filter my qs by robject_id and by project_name, for robject_id it works fine. I don't know how to get a project_name for filtering.

Moreover I Have to say, that in Tags ("no includes in urls") I did it with self.argss[0] and it works, but only form Tags ListView.

Code below:

```
class TagsListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Tag
    template_name = "tags/tag_list.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """A base view for displaying a list of objects."""
        # check if project exists
        try:
            project = Project.objects.get(name=args[0]) # it works fine
            # add project to view attributes
            self.project = project
        except Project.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        return super(TagsListView, self).get(request,*args, **kwargs)
```

This is what I discovered:

When I define my URL like that :

> ```
> url(r"^(\w+)/robjects/samples/$", SampleListView.as_view(), name='sample_list_view'),
> ```

All worrks. in my args is project_name and I can catch it by self.args[0]

But when I add  to that my args are empty,

> ```
> url(r"^(\w+)/robjects/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/samples/$", SampleListView.as_view(), name='sample_list_view'),
> ```

And when I define two kwargs like this :

```
url(r"^(?P<project_name>[\w\-]+)/robjects/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/samples/list/$",SampleListView.as_view(), name='sample_list_view'),
```

args empty - what I expected, kwargs both are OK and passed to the view

Is it a Django bug or is there any way to use self.args ? Are they overwrited by kwargs ?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

It's look like a bug. I tested it and when you pass args and kwargs into your url like:

```
url(r"^(\w+)/test1/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/test2/$", TestListView.as_view(), name='list_view'),
```

then the ListView returns empty tuple for args (it shouldn't).
It works when you pass only args or only kwargs into url.